# How to sort array based dictionary in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, dictionary

I have data that has been arranged in the following format

```
products{} = {'001':['001','Espreso',2.50], 
              '002':['002', 'Latte',1.50], 
              '003':['003', 'Orange Juice',1.00],
              '004':['003', 'Apple Juice',1.00], 
              }
```

I would like to sort the dictionary based on price so that I can get the following output.

```
products{} = {'003':['003', 'Orange Juice',1.00],
              '004':['003', 'Apple Juice',1.00],
              '002':['002', 'Latte',1.50],
              '001':['001','Espreso',2.50], 
              }
```

Being a newbie to python, I cant seem to find a proper guidance to sort this.
I have an array as value.

Please guide how to achiece this?
Is this even a correct way of assigning array as value to a key.?
Is this known as ordered dictionary?

Comment: `dict(sorted(products.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][-1]))`

Answer (score 0):

To sort dictionary you can pass it's items into a [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and initialize new dictionary from sorted key-value pairs.

To sort items of your dictionary by last element of value, we should pass to `key` argument of `sorted()` a `lambda` which will return receive key-value pair and return last element *(`-1` index)* of value *(`1` index)*.

Code:

```py
products = {
    '001':['001','Espreso',2.50], 
    '002':['002', 'Latte',1.50], 
    '003':['003', 'Orange Juice',1.00],
    '004':['003', 'Apple Juice',1.00]
}
sorted_products = dict(sorted(products.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][-1]))
```

Comment: ````sorted_products = dict(sorted(products.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1]))```

So If I want to sort via the name, I need to replace -1 to 1

Comment: Please note that this only works with python 3.7 or higher, as explained in the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Comment: @rasul1719435, yes, you're right, name is the second element with index `1`.

Comment: @Stef, this is the last year when python 3.6 is supported, so I think it's not necessary to mention that anymore.

Comment: @rasul1719435, if my answer helped you consider [to accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.